# How to install and use FLWM?

Tags: window-manager

I have used Lubuntu before, and like the low resource use and high speed of flwm.  However, when I install the `flwm` package using `apt-get` and log out, I do not get an option to use it.  Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I want `lxde` (Lightweight X(11) Desktop Environment), which includes flwm and various other components that make it work smoother with Ubuntu.  You can also install the `lubuntu-core` package, which installs the core Lubuntu desktop (includes flwm and OpenBox) without any extra programs.